# Find which vector is closest in value to another vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of coordinates:

```
a=[1 2]
```

I would like to find which of the following three coordinates are closest to `a`

```
b=[1 3; 4 2; 4 1]
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

I tried substracting b from a, but I don't know how to select the lowest value from the output

I would like to calculate ||a-b||^2, so assuming that a and b are coordinates on a 2 dimensional axis. I want to find the closest point in b to a

Comment: how do you define "closest"? All vectors in `b` have intersections with `a`. So there as close as possible. Please claryfy your question.

Comment: see edit, hope its clearer now

Answer (score 3):

Use [pdist](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/pdist.html) to calculate the distance and `min` to get the minimum.

Comment: +1, Good answer, but valid only if you have statistics toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Euclidean distance, you can use [`hypot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/hypot.html) and then the second output of [`min`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/min.html):

```
[~, ind] = min(hypot(b(:,1)-a(1), b(:,2)-a(2)));
```

The result `ind` gives the index of the row of `b` which minimizes distance.

Answer (score 0):

The lowest value can be selected using the 'min' function.

```
  [~,index] = min(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,b,a)),2))
```

Assuming that you are defining "closest" by L_1 norm.

Answer (score -1):

`norm(a - b)` will compute the distance between the two points